# Howto extract elements of type Double[]

Tags: java, arrays

I am doing the following conversion:

- a.) `String valuePhydX = Arrays.toString(getPhydX.getX());`

The type of getX() is `Double[] - Phyd`. 
As of now, the result from a.) is for example `[-0.19, 0.19] or [-0.27, 0.15]` which is fine!

Question: how to i change a.) so that I can extract the single elements of each arrays? in this case I want to use similar code as a.) but just to extract the value "-0.19", later on the value "0.19". Same goes for the value "-0.27" and then "0.15".

Comment: " so that I can extract the single elements of each arrays" Don't convert it to a string first. You're just making things harder for yourself.

Comment: What to do instead then?

Comment: Do still want a String object as the result?

Comment: Yes, String object as a result for printing out as text

Answer (score 0):

```
Double[] doubleArray = getPhydX.getX();
// either iterate on doubleArray directly or convert it to a list to use filters on
List<Double> list = Arrays.asList(doubleArray);
```

use lambda expressions or a loop to iterate through the list to get the individual values.
[Lambda/filters can be used in java 8](https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/examples/find-element-in-list/)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate through the array like this

```
Double[] doubleArray = getPhydX.getX();

for (int i = 0; i < doubleArray.length; i++) { 
     // accessing each element of array 
     double x = doubleArray[i]; 
     System.out.print(x + " "); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to accessing the array using an index, assuming the array always has two elements do

```
Double[] result = getPhydX.getX();
double d1 = result[0];
double d2 = result[1];
```

or as strings

```
String s1 = String.valueOf(result [0]);
String s2 = String.valueOf(result [1]);
```

If the result array from `getX` varies in size you must check `.length` on the array before trying to access via an index.